# understanding alias in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand how to correctly create an alias.

I'm going off a definition of

> Two expressions are aliases of each other if they have the same
>   location associated with them.

Below is an image of a box diagram showing memory allocations

[image]

The goal is to create an alias for `a[1]`

The edge of a box is refers to the location and the circle inside refers to the value stored.

I recognized that `b[1]` has a value which is the address of `a[1]`.  So

**I *think* in order to create an alias all I have to do is create some variable and assign it the value of `b[1]`.**

To test if my assumption is correct I tried the following:

```
struct T *alias = *b[2];

printf("alias location is: %p\n", alias);
printf("a[2] location is: %p\n", a[2]);
```

Which produces:

```
alias location is: 0x561936c62320
a[2] location is: 0x561936c62320
```

The addresses match but I'm confused if I did it right. Don't I need to use the `&` operator in the `printf()` function in order to print the actual address? When I do that:

```
struct T *alias = *b[2];

printf("alias location is: %p\n", &alias);
printf("a[2] location is: %p\n", &a[2]);
```

I get incorrect addresses:

```
alias location is: 0x7ffdee2cd320
a[2] location is: 0x7ffdee2cd340
```

Can someone please explain if I'm doing it correctly and if not how to do it correctly?

Comment: This is not `alias` - this is pointers. `&alias` gives you a pointer to the memory location where `alias` is - which in turn points to a memory location where `struct T` is located

Comment: Your definition is most misleading. Two _pointers_ can _point_ to the same location. I don't like the wording "have the same location associated". They literally _store_ the location of other variables.

Comment: "Alias" has a very specific meaning and this is not one of them. These are independent pointers that happen to share the same value, not aliases. In other languages (e.g. C++) there are more alias-like features such as references where two things can be considered the same, modifying one reference modifies all other references to the same thing since they're one and the same.

Answer (score 1):

“Alias” simply means an alternative name. In C, what we mean by “name” in the meaning of “alias” is an lvalue. According to C 2018 6.3.2.1 1, “An lvalue is an expression… that potentially designates an object…” If you have two lvalues for same thing, you have two aliases for the that thing (or you might designate one as the primary name and the other as an alias).

Most simply, after `int b;`, `b` is an lvalue for the object named by `b`. And, after `int *p = &b;`, `*p` is an lvalue for the same object. Then `b` and `*p` are aliases of the same object.

The meanings of the diagrams you show are unclear. Part of it shows `a` and `b` as simple scalar objects. Another part shows them as arrays. Without more context and explanation, it is not possible to interpret it reliably.

If we have an `int a[1]` and an `int b[1]`, and the compiler happens to put `b` in memory immediately after `a`, then `a[1]` is in some sense an alias for `b[0]`, but it is improper to use it, because the rules in the C standard do not define the behavior of accessing an array out of bounds, even if we somehow know what follows it in memory.

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple rule that usually holds for `block-statement` (e.g., `{...}`): `(a)` Considering automatic allocation (or the allocation that occurs *because of* a function call *upon the stack*) and `(b)` Considering user allocation (or the allocation that occurs *because of* the size of a `struct` or `union`):

In the case of `(a)`, the `sizeof operator` is `summed` to determine the amount of `stack allocation`.

In the case of `(b)`, the `sizeof operator` is `multiplied` to determine the location of `array offset`.

*The caveat is that other storage classes can have different outcomes, but these are typically the ones you will have the most experience with when programming in C.*